# How to append a column to a 2d numpy array in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have two numpy arrays.  One is a 2d matrix that has 3 columns and 4 rows.  The second numpy array is a 1d array with 4 values.  Is there a way to append the second numpy array as a column to the first numpy array in Python 2.7?

For example if these were my two numpy arrays:

```
arr2d = np.matrix(
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6], 
[7, 8, 9], 
[10, 11, 12]])

column_to_add = np.array([10, 40, 70, 100])
```

I'd like the output to look like this

```
    [[1, 2, 3, 10],
    [4, 5, 6, 40], 
    [7, 8, 9, 70], 
    [10, 11, 12, 100]]
```

I tried using

```
output = np.hstack((arr2d, column_to_add))
```

but I got an error that says:

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have the same number of dimensions.
```

Any and all help is appreciated.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Correct the number of dimensions: `np.concatenate((arr2d, column_to_add[:,None]), axis=1)`.  The `[:,None]` makes the 1d array into a 2d column array.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr2d = np.matrix(
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6], 
[7, 8, 9], 
[10, 11, 12]])

column_to_add = np.array([10, 40, 70, 100])

output = np.column_stack((arr2d, column_to_add))
```

**Output:**

```
matrix([[  1,   2,   3,  10],
        [  4,   5,   6,  40],
        [  7,   8,   9,  70],
        [ 10,  11,  12, 100]])
```